# Messages not receiving to Indian numbers using Twilio

Tags: c#-4.0, twilio

I am using Twilio to send messages to indian numbers. I have read [this guide](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices)

What is transactional messages? Where can i set it? I want to send messages even after 9:00 P.M and also to DND activated numbers. Is it possible by transactional messages? Can any one please help me with this aspect.....

Comment: I'd suggest sending an email to help@twilio.com.  Our support team can work with you to see if your user case fits into the Transational message category.

Comment: In India, you cannot send after 9 PM to 9 AM whatsoever. This is the law imposed by the ministry of telecom.